# Executable files not in path - GO

Tags: go, command-line

I'm trying to call a built in command for the command prompt and I'm getting errors I don't understand.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("del", "C:\trial\now.txt")
// Reboot if needed
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
exec: "del": executable file not found in %PATH%
exit status 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Specify the full path to the `del` command. I am not sure how it's under windows, but on linux if the command is `del` you'd run `/usr/bin/del` most likely.

Comment: I'm on windows. Any idea where that is?

Comment: and why it is I have to do that? shouldn't del be in the path?

Comment: There is no "del.exe", it's a command built into the Windows shell. See my answer for solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`del` is not an executable, it's a built-in command. `exec.Command` allows you to fork out to another executable. To use shell commands, you would have to call the shell executable, and pass in the built-in command (and parameters) you want executed:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "del C:\\trial\\now.txt")
```

Note that you also have to escape backslashes in strings as above, or use backtick-quoted strings:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", `del C:\trial\now.txt`)
```

However, if you just want to delete a file, you're probably better off using [`os.Remove`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Remove) to directly delete a file rather than forking out to the shell to do so.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the problem with the executable, your path string is not what you think it is.

```
cmd := exec.Command("del", "C:\trial\now.txt")
```

The `\t` will be interpreted as a tab, and the `\n` as a newline.

To avoid this, use ``` `` ``` which has no special characters and no escape, not even `\`. A great relief for Windows users!

```
cmd := exec.Command("del", `C:\trial\now.txt`)
```

See [String Literals in the Go Language Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) for more.