# Executable file not found in %PATH% golang

Tags: go, glide-golang

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    //"log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("dir")
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("cmd.Run: %s failed: %s\n", err, err)
    }
    outStr, errStr := string(stdout.Bytes()), string(stderr.Bytes())
    if len(errStr) > 1 {
        fmt.Printf("out:\n%s\nerr:\n%s\n", outStr, errStr)
    }

    fmt.Printf(outStr)
}
```

*Hi guys, whenever I try to run this file with go it shows me This error "cmd.Run: exec: "dir": executable file not found in %PATH% failed:". I have golang in my PATH but it still failed *

Comment: Perhaps `dir`is not a program but a command from windows shell interpreter

Comment: So how do I run commands for windows shell interpreter with GO?

Comment: See [Executable files not in path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44833044/12258482).  Use [os.ReadDir](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadDir) to get a directory listing.

Comment: Perhaps this `exec.Command("cmd", "/C dir")`

Comment: There is no reason to call an external command to read a dir. This is either a XY problem or just related to bad PATH and/or dir not being an executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dir** is not an executable file in Windows, rather it is an internal command of Command prompt. You need to pass dir to command prompt.
Your command would look like this:

> cmd.exe /c dir

You can implement it like this:

> args := strings.Split("/c dir"," ")

> cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe",args...)

Pass your command line arguments like this, strings.Split() will split "/c dir" into all substrings separated by " " and returns a slice of the substrings between those separators.

Also if you need to print dir of a specific location you can set the working directory of the command:

> cmd.Dir = filepath.Join("C:","Windows")

filepath.Join joins any number of path elements into a single path, separating them with an OS specific Separator.

Add the following packages into your file

import (
"os"
"path/filepath"
"strings"
)

To print the result you can connect your output and error to the standard output, and standard error.

```
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = &os.Stderr
```

Your overall code would be:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    args := strings.Split("/c dir"," ")
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe",args...)

    cmd.Dir = filepath.Join("C:","Windows")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("cmd.Run: %s failed: %s\n", err, err)
    }

}
```